# Gradual on hover background color change on list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay so what the code is supposed to do, is change the background color of the li tag. But, it has to be done in an animated way. i.e. the background color shouldn't change right away. The background color should gradually be set over the course of a few seconds.

I have written this, and even though it does set the background color nicely, it doesn't do it gradually:

```
// Subtle navigation on hover color animation

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".navigation li").hover(

    function () {
        // Over
        $(this).animate(
        $(this).css("background", "rgba(159,223,188, 0.9)"),
        300);
    },

    function () {
        // Out            
        $(this).animate(
        $(this).css("background", "none"),
        300);
    }

    );
});
```

The html is quite simple:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for any pointers in the right direction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stick to a JavaScript solution, take a look at the [Color animation plugin](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/).

Alternatively I would suggest using a CSS3 transition. You don't even need JavaScript:

```
li {
    background-color: rgba(159,223,188, 0.9);
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.3s linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.3s linear;
    transition: background-color 0.3s linear;
}

li:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/r5vhf/)

Comment: Niiiice :-D Works very nicely. Whats the browser support like for this?

Comment: Here's the browser support for [CSS3 transitions](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions) and here for [CSS3 colors](http://caniuse.com/css3-colors). It's basically the same.

Answer (score 2):

You should do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".navigation li").hover(

    function () {
        // Over
        $(this).animate({
            background: 'rgba(159,223,188, 0.9)'
        }, 300);
    },

    function () {
        // Out            
        $(this).animate({
            background: 'none'
        }, 300);
    }

    );
});
```

You don't need the `.css()`, You just pass the styling to the `.animate()` function. You can olso pass multiple effects.

Go [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for more information.

Comment: Tried this but it doesn't work. Now the background color doesn't change at all on hover ? :-/

Comment: Jeah, because you will need the color animation plugin!

Answer (score 0):

**You can also try doing this:**

Add the following CSS to your second function

```
            "background": "none",
            "transition-property": "background",
            "transition-duration": "1s",
            "transition-timing-function": "linear"
```

check the code below

you can increase the value of "transition-duration": "1s" to any seconds for more delays.

Hope this helps

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".navigation li").hover(

        function(){
            // Over
            $(this).animate(
                $(this).css("background","rgba(159,223,188, 0.9)"), 
               300
            );
        },
        function(){
            // Out            
            $(this).animate(
                $(this).css(
                    {
                    "background": "none",
                    "transition-property": "background",
                    "transition-duration": "1s",
                    "transition-timing-function": "linear"
                    }

                ), 
                300
            );
        }

    );
});
```